# Is it possible to prevent the win7 suspend state while using JDownloader or MiPony using script?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, suspend

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent windows 7 to go to suspend while using JDownloader or MiPony? using scripting ? perhaps powercfg command ?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on the [Windows Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/86151-how-disable-sleep-mode-programmatically.html), you can try an application called [Insomnia](http://cesso.org/Samples/Insomnia/Insomnia.zip).